# landscape list on camera surface view

Tags: android, camera, android-listview, android-camera, android-orientation

I'm building a camera application where I want to implement the same feature android has in their settings menu:

this is the camera scene settings in portrait mode:

[image: camera scene settings in portrait mode]

this is the camera scene settings in landscape mode:

[image: camera scene settings in landscape mode]

the orientation of the list and the button changes but the application isn't recreated I guess this happens with a orientationEventListener I managed to rotate the buttons with a  rotation animation this way but not the settings list...
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you post how yours looks or a sketch of your list after change?

Comment: mine looks like the first image only rotated 90 degrees...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't actually changing the orientation then you are going to need something that spins in the opposite direction from a list (horizontal like gallery or horizontalscrollview).  I would recommend removing the list and changing it to a scrollview.  when the rotation changes then change it to a horizontalscrollview and rotate each item 90 degrees. It might take a little hacking to get it in the right position and such, but might be your easiest solution.

Comment: not sure if its the easiest solution but it seems to work... with a lot of hacking!

Answer (score 0):

Use Only Relative Layot while making the XML for camera.
make another layout cantaining the listview of your various items.
then in your java file , iflate your list.xml on your camerapreview.xml..
it worked in mine , workout , it will.

Comment: the inflation works fine in general, but I need it to inflate as a landscape list... at the moment it only shows as portrait

Comment: in manifest file , inside the activity tag specify android:configChanges="orientation" then in java file overwrite public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
 {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

  landscape =(Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE == newConfig.orientation);
  resize();
 }

Comment: but then the onDestroy/oncreate will be called and the camera preview will pause and need to be restarted.... this isn't the behavior of the android camera...